# How can I Log ssh login passwords attempts?

Tags: password, openssh

I need to log ssh passwords attempts. I read somewhere you could get this done by patching openssh but I don't know if that is the correct way to get this done.

I am using Arch.

EDIT:

I want to get the passwords people tried to guess to gain access to my system.
It could be with journalctl or get piled in a text file. 
If the person let's say types 1234 and tries to get access I want something like

"ssh loggin attempt failed, tried user "admin" with password "1234"

Comment: Have you looked in the log files, attempts are usually logged there.

Comment: Yes, but only log attempts, not the passwords used in the log attempt.

Comment: It is not clear from your question that it is that what you are looking for, please update it with the exact thing that you need, and describing what you are going to do with the information doesn't hurt either (as there might be other ways to achieve your goal, like downloading a database of  passwords from somewhere)

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You will end up logging user's mistyped passwords, which is a great starting point to guess their *real* password from the plaintext. Logging such a thing may even be illegal in your jurisdiction, and it dramatically *decreases* overall user security. Use keys instead and you will never have to worry about password attempts.

Comment: my system is only used for me. I consider this a great idea.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think is a better answer is to download the LongTail SSH honeypot which is a hacked version of openssh to log username, password, source IP and port, and Client software and version.

The install script is at https://github.com/wedaa/LongTail-Log-Analysis/blob/master/install_openssh.sh

I also do analytics at http://longtail.it.marist.edu

Answer (score 1):

If you do this, (1) log to authpriv, (2) make sure authpriv can be read only by root. See syslog.conf or rsyslog.conf for details.  Next, you'll have to hack the source code. At some point the password will be sent to a library call `crypt`. Just before that, use the logging code to log the input string. Alternatively to hacking the ssh code, you can use LD_PRELOAD to intercept the `crypt` call; then you must start your `sshd` daemon with the LD_PRELOAD environment variable set to your new library (of one or two calls).

For extra-security, consider encrypting the output string using a symmetric key. This isn't very good security, but it will prevent accidental exposure to good passwords (the scenario where sshd captures your own passwords and someone walks by while you've got the contents of authpriv on the screen).

For more on intercepting lib calls with LD_PRELOAD, see https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/

How to do syslog in C: 
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Syslog-Example.html. If you hack the ssh code, there will already be logging function; just copy and modify as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question when trying to recover SFTP passwords.

I prepared 2 complete working examples for people facing the same challenges in the future.

#### Variant 0: Patch OpenSSH

[Creating a patched OpenSSH docker image to log all passwords](https://metamorphant.de/blog/posts/2021-04-14-ssh-server-opensshd-logging-passwords/) is simple. Basically you have to add a line at the relevant location for the password check:

```
sed -e 's/^\([ \t]*\)\(struct passwd \*pw = authctxt->pw;\)/\1logit("Login attempt by username '\''%s'\'', password '\''%s'\''", authctxt->user, password);\n\1\2/' -i auth-passwd.c
```

This will just convert

```c
    struct passwd \*pw = authctxt->pw;
```

to

```c
    logit("Login attempt by username '\''%s'\'', password '\''%s'\''", authctxt->user, password);
    struct passwd \*pw = authctxt->pw;
```

See [the Dockerfile including the patch](https://gist.github.com/JohannesFKnauf/8f1e00c823a8fdba6eccd75a89f420f8) to learn more about the complete build process.

#### Variant 1: Roll your own SSH server

Not sure, if OpenSSH is a fixed requirement for you or if an alternative SSH implementation might suit you just as well. If OpenSSH is not a strict requirement, you can e.g. [create an SFTP server logging all passwords using Apache Mina on Java](https://metamorphant.de/blog/posts/2021-04-13-ssh-server-apache-mina-recover-sftp-passwords-automic-uc4/).

The essential part for plugging the password-logging into Apache Mina is implementing the `PasswordAuthenticator` interface:

```java
package de.metamorphant.examples.chattysshd;

import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.AsyncAuthException;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.password.PasswordAuthenticator;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.password.PasswordChangeRequiredException;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggingPasswordAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticator {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingPasswordAuthenticator.class);

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session)
            throws PasswordChangeRequiredException, AsyncAuthException {
        logger.debug(String.format("Login attempt by user '%s' with password '%s'\n", username, password));
        return false; // Authentication with our dummy server always fails
    }
}
```

Then, you still have to inject it into your server:

```java
...
    SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
...
    sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new LoggingPasswordAuthenticator());
...
```

Look into the [complete working example for a password-logging SFTP server implemented with Apache Mina](https://github.com/JohannesFKnauf/chatty-sshd) to learn more.

#### Variant 2: Use a preconfigured honeypot tool

Depending on your use case, you might also want to consider a full-fledged SSH honeypot. Typically, these tools comprise much more than just logging passwords, e.g. logging the complete shell interaction of an attacker. Examples:

- https://github.com/desaster/kippo
- https://github.com/cowrie/cowrie
- https://github.com/madirish/kojoney2
- https://github.com/droberson/ssh-honeypot
- https://github.com/aabed/dockpot
- https://github.com/tnich/honssh
- https://github.com/jaksi/sshesame
- https://github.com/magisterquis/sshhipot

I don't have experience with any of those, though.